# Ignoring code-first migrations for integration tests

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to setup SQL Server CE 4.0 as my Test Database in order to run integration tests, as described in this article: http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2013/01/06/using-sql-compact-for-integration-tests-with-entity-framework/

These are all the projects in my solution:

- UnitTests
- Website
- DataAccessLayer
- Core

I added a SQL Compact CE 4.0 reference and connectionString to the app.config file on the UnitTests project and then tried to run the update-database command:

> update-database -ProjectName DataAccessLayer -StartupProjectName UnitTests -Verbose

This works fine for most migrations but it stops short of finishing and then I get this error:

> Direct column renaming is not supported by SQL Server Compact. To
>   rename a column in SQL Server Compact, you will need to recreate it.

Is there a way that I can turn off migrations and just re-create the entire database JUST for the unit tests projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Just had to set the Database initializer on the unit tests project:

`System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());`

I call this from the FixtureSetup method on my unit test project.